# Javascript check an object if it has a certain property value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

```
{
  "firstRoom": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "age": 21
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "age": 31
    },
    {
      "name": "C",
      "age": 41
    }
  ],
  "secondRoom": [
    {
      "name": "FF",
      "age": 21
    },
    {
      "name": "GG",
      "age": 31
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I check my object to see if the array `secondRoom` has the property `name` with the `value` of "FF" ??

I tried like this:

```
if("secondRoom" in rooms){

    if("FF" in rooms.secondRoom.name){
        alert('yap');
                       }else{
                       alert('nop');
                       }

}else{
    alert('no room today');
}
```

It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var b = rooms.secondRoom && rooms.secondRoom.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.name === "FF";
});
alert(b ? 'yap' : 'nop');
```

Or, if you want to be sure those properties are own ones and not inherited,

```
var b = rooms.hasOwnProperty("secondRoom") && rooms.secondRoom.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("name") && obj.name==="FF";
});
alert(b ? 'yap' : 'nop');
```